# Opposite command to ENTRYPOINT

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Is there a way to run a command on container stop either using the `Dockerfile` or in `docker-compose.yml` using Docker Compose? Essentially I want a command that runs on container exit (opposite to `ENTRYPOINT`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, ENTRYPOINT can do that.  It takes the CMD as command-line arguments.  Usually your ENTRYPOINT script will want to `exec "$@"` to run the CMD after doing its setup, but if you're willing to take on the responsibility of being process ID 1, you can run CMD as a subprocess and then do stuff afterwards.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
echo "BEFORE"
"$@"
STATUS=$?
echo "AFTER"
exit $STATUS
```

Note that the set of things you can usefully do at termination is pretty limited since your filesystem is about to go away.

Also note that this requires you to run your "normal" process as CMD, but for reasons like this I tend to think of that as better practice in any case.  Your Dockerfile would look something like

```
...
COPY entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["whateverd", "--foreground"]
```